# Allow docker container to connect to a local/host postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, qgis

I've recently been playing around with Docker and QGIS and have installed a container following the instructions in [this tutorial](http://kartoza.com/qgis-desktop-in-docker/).

Everything works great, although I am unable to connect to a localhost postgres database that contains all my GIS data. I figure this is because my postgres database is not configured to accept remote connections and have been editing the postgres conf files to allow remote connections using the  instructions in [this article](http://blog.jsinh.in/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-postgresql-database-server/#.VZqPgnXInK5).

I'm still getting an error message when I try and connect to my database running QGIS in Docker: could not connect to server: `Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections to port 5433?`
The postgres server is running, and I've edited my **pg_hba.conf** file to allow connections from a range of IP addresses (172.17.0.0/32). I had previously queried the IP address of the docker container using `docker ps` and although the IP address changes, it has so far always been in the range 172.17.0.x

Any ideas why I can't connect to this database? Probably something very simple I imagine!

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04; Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 255, accepted):

#### TL;DR

1. Use `172.17.0.0/16` as IP address range, not `172.17.0.0/32`.
2. Don't use `localhost` to connect to the PostgreSQL database on your host, but the host's IP instead. To keep the container portable, start the container with the `--add-host=database:<host-ip>` flag and use `database` as hostname for connecting to PostgreSQL.
3. Make sure PostgreSQL is configured to listen for connections on all IP addresses, not just on `localhost`. Look for the setting `listen_addresses` in PostgreSQL's configuration file, typically found in `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf` (credits to @DazmoNorton).

#### Long version

`172.17.0.0/32` is not a *range* of IP addresses, but a single address (namly `172.17.0.0`). No Docker container will ever get that address assigned, because it's the network address of the Docker bridge (`docker0`) interface.

When Docker starts, it will create a new bridge network interface, that you can easily see when calling `ip a`:

```
$ ip a
...
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.42.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see, in my case, the `docker0` interface has the IP address `172.17.42.1` with a netmask of `/16` (or `255.255.0.0`). This means that the network address is `172.17.0.0/16`.

The IP address is randomly assigned, but without any additional configuration, it will always be in the `172.17.0.0/16` network. For each Docker container, a random address from that range will be assigned.

This means, if you want to grant access from all possible containers to your database, use `172.17.0.0/16`.

Comment: hey thanks for your comments. I've changed my `pg_hba.conf` to the address you suggested, but still get the same connection error message after stopping and restarting the postgres service. I've added the line under my ipv4 connections - is there somewhere else I'm supposed to add the address you suggest? Alternatively in my QGIS app running in Docker do I need to change the postgres connection info? For example, if I'm connecting from within a docker container is the host still 'localhost'?

Comment: Ah, that's an important point. No, `localhost` is not the host system inside your Docker container. Try connecting to the host system's public IP address. To keep the container portable, you can also start the container with the `--add-host=database:<host-ip>` and simply use `database` as hostname to connect to your PostgreSQL host from within the Docker container.

Comment: I needed one more piece.  I also had to edit `/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf` and add my server's `eth0` IP address to `listen_addresses`.  By default `listen_addresses` has postgres bind to `localhost` only.

Comment: @DzamoNorton, thanks for the hint! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @helmbert `host-ip` is ip address of virtual machine or docker container?

Comment: @Mr.D with "host", I mean the machine (either virtual or physical) that the container is run on, not the container itself.

Comment: The entire 'Long version' of this answer doesn't make sense.  Fundamentally, `172.17.0.0/32` **is** a range of IP addresses - that's what the `/32` is - CIDR notation of an address range!  While the 'TL;DR' might solve people's problems, it does so without any real understanding of IP Address ranges.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake that others may also encounter. I was trying to run postgres container with `--add-host:database:<172.17.0.1>`, while I should've started the other container (e.g. node server trying to connect to postgres) with `add-host` flag.

Comment: Point no 3 is very important. I took 2 days to resolve it and finally with this point my problem got resolved. Thanks...

Comment: For people who see docker spawning containers in different subnets (`172.17`, `172.20`, etc. Put this in your `pg_hba.conf`:

`host    all             all             172.0.0.0/8            md5`

Comment: To get this working I also had to configure the firewall to allow connections from up range, as connections are from another machine

Comment: `172.17.0.0/16` didn't work for me, i had to do `172.17.0.%` instead
i suppose the equivalent to `/16` would be `172.17.%.%`

Answer (score 202):

## Simple Solution

The newest version of docker (18.03) offers a built in port forwarding solution. Inside your docker container simply have the db host set to `host.docker.internal`. This will be forwarded to the host the docker container is running on.

Documentation for this is here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

Comment: is `host.docker.internal` limited to macs only?

Comment: @Dragas according to the docs it will "not work outside of the Mac", but the same DNS name is mentioned in the docs for Docker for Windows, so I think it's limited to "Docker for...". Either way it's development-only: you're not meant to ship a docker image that uses this.

Comment: Only working with windows and mac. On my case ubuntu is not working

Comment: This works for WSL2 Ubuntu.  My specific case: WSL2 Docker container (Flask app) accessing a WSL2 installed postgresql.

Comment: The docs say " This is for development purpose and does not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop.". I will be connecting to a remote database in my production setup as well. What should I do in that case?

Comment: As @MazharAli pointed out, this is slightly mislead as it only works locally/in development with docker desktop. In production, you should use the service/container name as the hostname. Read this for more: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: and if we don't have a container for our postgres? (i.e. it is running locally?)

Answer (score 84):

### Docker for Mac solution

### 17.06 onwards

Thanks to @Birchlabs' comment, now it is tons easier with this [special Mac-only DNS name available](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host):

```
docker run -e DB_PORT=5432 -e DB_HOST=docker.for.mac.host.internal
```

From 17.12.0-cd-mac46, `docker.for.mac.host.internal` should be used instead of `docker.for.mac.localhost`. See [release note](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac46-2018-01-09-stable) for details.

### Older version

@helmbert's answer well explains the issue. But Docker for Mac [does not expose the bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host), so I had to do this trick to workaround the limitation:

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24
```

Open `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf` and add this line:

```
host    all             all             10.200.10.1/24            trust
```

Open `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf` and edit change `listen_addresses`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Reload service and launch your container:

```
$ PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres pg_ctl reload
$ docker run -e DB_PORT=5432 -e DB_HOST=10.200.10.1 my_app
```

What this workaround does is basically same with @helmbert's answer, but uses an IP address that is attached to `lo0` instead of `docker0` network interface.

Comment: Is this still current as of 4 April 2017?

Comment: I like this way which will not expose database. BTW, can I use this on CentOS? I got the error: alias: Unknown host when I tried to use the alias command you provide.

Comment: There is a better way on macOS, as of Docker 17.06.0-rc1-ce-mac13 (June 1st 2017). containers recognise the host `docker.for.mac.localhost`. this is the IP of your host machine. lookup its entry in the container's hosts database like so:  `docker run alpine /bin/sh -c 'getent hosts docker.for.mac.localhost'`

Comment: Seems like it changed to `host.docker.internal` since 18.03, other options are still available but deprecated ([Source](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-18030-ce-mac59-2018-03-26)).

Answer (score 61):

## Simple solution

Just add `--network=host` to `docker run`. That's all!

This way container will use the host's network, so `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` will point to the host (by default they point to a container). Example:

```
docker run -d --network=host \
  -e "DB_DBNAME=your_db" \
  -e "DB_PORT=5432" \
  -e "DB_USER=your_db_user" \
  -e "DB_PASS=your_db_password" \
  -e "DB_HOST=127.0.0.1" \
  --name foobar foo/bar
```

Comment: Be careful! This solution, that is the right one in my opinion, does not work for macOS. Don't waste your time trying to figure out why it is not working. Take a look at: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2716

Comment: Works on Debian. Tried changing postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf but this is simpler and faster.

Comment: Also, one cannot be able to publish ports 

Comment: This worked for me on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-1022-aws x86_64)`, thanks

Answer (score 32):

The solution posted here does not work for me. Therefore, I am posting this answer to help someone facing similar issue.

**Note**: This solution works for Windows 10 as well, please check comment below.

OS: **Ubuntu 18**
PostgreSQL: **9.5 (Hosted on Ubuntu)**
Docker: **Server Application** (which connects to PostgreSQL)

I am using docker-compose.yml to build application.

**STEP 1:** Please add `host.docker.internal:<docker0 IP>`

```
version: '3'
services:
  bank-server:
    ...
    depends_on:
      ....
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1"
```

To find IP of docker `i.e. 172.17.0.1 (in my case)` you can use:

```
$> ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
```

**OR**

```
$> ip a
1: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**STEP 2:** In postgresql.conf, change listen_addresses to `listen_addresses = '*'`

**STEP 3:** In pg_hba.conf, add this line

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

**STEP 4:** Now restart postgresql service using, `sudo service postgresql restart`

**STEP 5:** Please use `host.docker.internal` hostname to connect database from Server Application.
Ex: `jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/bankDB`

Enjoy!!

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<your_version>/main/postgresql.conf` for those who want to edit postgres conf

Comment: I have validated these steps in Windows 10 along with Docker. This is working well. Only things to note: use ipconfig in Step 1 and in Step 4, to restart postgresql services goto Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> View Local Service and then search for Postgresql service and restart them.

Comment: Thank you, step 2 and 3 solved my problem. In my case, I set the `method` for the new `pg_hba`  entry to `password`. Also, you don't have to open access to all IP (`0.0.0.0/0`), but can instead use the docker bridge IP (use `ip -h -c a` to find that IP), in my case it was `172.17.0.1/16`

Comment: If you followed this method with Ubuntu and get `could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address`, then just change the host to the local Docker IP `172.17.0.1` and it should work.

Comment: extra_hosts:
       - "172.17.0.1:172.17.0.2". does not work and all combinations:; Operation timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you want to know the IP of docker when you need to know the IP of your localhost from the perspective of the container??

Answer (score 15):

you can pass `--network=host` during `docker run` command to access `localhost` inside container.

Ex:

```
docker run --network=host docker-image-name:latest
```

In case you want to pass env variables with localhost use `--env-file` paramater to access environment variables inside container.

Ex:

```
docker run --network=host --env-file .env-file-name docker-image-name:latest
```

Note: pass the parameters before docker image name otherwise parameters will not work. (I faced this, so heads up!)

Comment: how will you write this in docker-compose?

Comment: Be advised that this option discards port mapping. In a host network mode the container shares the host’s networking namespace. I.e. if your app in container runs on :80, it will be available on :80 on the host. https://docs.docker.com/network/host/

Comment: And it works only on Linux.

Answer (score 7):

for docker-compose you can try just add

```
network_mode: "host"
```

example :

```
version: '2'
services:
  feedx:
    build: web
    ports:
    - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
    network_mode: "host"
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode

Comment: adding networkd_mode to host break the connection between another containers

Answer (score 7):

Let me try explain what i did.

### Postgresql

First of all I did the configuration needed to make sure my Postgres Database was accepting connections from outside.

open `pg_hba.conf` and add in the end the following line:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

open `postgresql.conf` and look for `listen_addresses` and modify there like this:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Make sure the line above is not commented with a `#`

-> Restart your database

***OBS***: This is not the recommended configuration for a production environment

Next, I looked for my host’s `ip`. I was using localhosts ip `127.0.0.1`, but the container doesn’t see it, so the Connection Refused message in question shows up when running the container. After a long search in web about this, I read that the container sees the internal ip from your local network (That one your router attributes to every device that connects to it, i’m not talking about the IP that gives you access to the internet). That said, i opened a terminal and did the following:

### Look for local network ip

Open a terminal or CMD

(MacOS/Linux)

```
$ ifconfig
```

(Windows)

```
$ ipconfig
```

This command will show your network configuration information.
And looks like this:

```
en4: 
    ether d0:37:45:da:1b:6e 
    inet6 fe80::188d:ddbe:9796:8411%en4 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x7 
    inet 192.168.0.103 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

Look for the one that is active.

In my case, my local network ip was `192.168.0.103`

With this done, I ran the container.

### Docker

Run the container with the `--add-host` parameter, like this:

```
$ docker run --add-host=aNameForYourDataBaseHost:yourLocalNetWorkIp --name containerName -di -p HostsportToBind:containerPort imageNameOrId
```

In my case I did:

```
$ docker run --add-host=db:192.168.0.103 --name myCon -di -p 8000:8000 myImage
```

I’m using `Django`, so the `8000` port is the default.

#### Django Application

The configuration to access the database was:

In `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': ‘myDataBaseName',
            'USER': ‘username',
            'PASSWORD': '123456',
            'HOST': '192.168.0.103',
            'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

## References

About `-p` flag:
[Connect using network port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)

About `docker run`:
[Docker run documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Interesting article:
[Docker Tip #35: Connect to a Database Running on Your Docker Host](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-35-connect-to-a-database-running-on-your-docker-host)

Comment: that solution worked for me, its works with 192.x.x.x if but does not working with localhost or 127.x.x.x

Comment: Same, using 192.x.x.x worked for me instead of localhost in Django.

Answer (score 6):

To set up something simple that allows a Postgresql connection *from* the docker container to my localhost I used this in postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

And added this pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           password
```

Then do a restart. My client *from* the docker container (which was at 172.17.0.2) could then connect to Postgresql running on my localhost using host:password, database, username and password.

Comment: `172.17.0.0/16 ` is this the default ip for docker? If not, is this the same for everyone?

Answer (score 6):

## 3 STEPS SOLUTION

### 1. Update docker-compose file

First, since the database is local we need to bind the host network to the container by adding the following configuration to the container service

```yaml
services:
    ...
    my-web-app:
        ...
        extra_hosts:
          -  "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        ...
    ...
```

### 2. Update /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

If the file doesn't exists under this dir use `find / -name 'pg_hba.conf'` to find it.

Add the following line under the comment tag `# IPv4 local connections:`

```
host    all             all             172.17.0.1/16           md5
```

### 3. Update `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`

If the file doesn't exists under this dir use `find / -name 'postgresql.conf'` to find it.

find the following line (The line might be commented)

```
#listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

And change it to the following line to be able to connect to postgres from localhost and `172.17.0.1`

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,172.17.0.1'
```

You can also change it to the following, But this is not recommended for production since it will expose the database to the world (meaning any IP address can connect to the database)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Finally don't forget to:

1. Restart the postgres service using `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`
2. Update the connection string host to `host.docker.internal`

Answer (score 4):

You can add multiple listening address for better security.

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost,172.17.0.1'
```

Adding `listen_addresses = '*'` isn't a good option, which is very dangerous and expose your postgresql database to the wild west.

Comment: oh yeah on my work previous CTO made "*" and someone connected to our server postgres and started crypto mining!

Answer (score 3):

## In Ubuntu:

First You have to check that is the Docker Database port is Available in your system by following command -

```
sudo iptables -L -n
```

Sample OUTPUT:

```
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:3306
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:22
```

Here `3306` is used as Docker Database Port on 172.17.0.2 IP, If this port is not available Run the following command -

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, You can easily access the Docker Database from your local system by following configuration

```
  host: 172.17.0.2 
  adapter: mysql
  database: DATABASE_NAME
  port: 3307
  username: DATABASE_USER
  password: DATABASE_PASSWORD
  encoding: utf8
```

## In CentOS:

First You have to check that is the Docker Database port is Available in your firewall by following command -

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Sample OUTPUT:

```
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno79841677
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  **ports: 3307/tcp**
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Here `3307` is used as Docker Database Port on 172.17.0.2 IP, If this port is not available Run the following command -

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3307/tcp
```

In server, You can add the port permanently

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=3307/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Now, You can easily access the Docker Database from your local system by the above configuration.

Comment: I know this is old but *Now, You can easily access the Docker Database from your local system by following configuration* - you have this the wrong way around. He has a local database, and a docker app trying to connect to that local db not the other way around

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, above solutions don't work for anyone. Use below statement to connect from docker to host postgres (on mac):

```
psql --host docker.for.mac.host.internal -U postgres
```

Comment: I had to add `RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client` to my Dockerfile and `psql --host host.docker.internal` worked for me  (also on a mac)

Answer (score 0):

One more thing needed for my setup was to add

```
172.17.0.1  localhost
```

to `/etc/hosts`

so that Docker would point to `172.17.0.1` as the DB hostname, and not rely on a changing outer ip to find the DB. Hope this helps someone else with this issue!

Comment: This is a bad solution. Localhost should typically point to 127.0.0.1. Changing it might have undesired consequences, even if in this particular case it works.

Comment: A better way is to set up a `database` host with `--add-host=database:172.17.0.1` when running the container. Then point your app to that host. This avoids hard-coding an IP address inside a container.

Comment: the `--add-host=database:172.17.0.1` is preferable

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to connect even if you followed all the above steps ,please check to enable firewall on 5433 or 5432.
on host machine

```
sudo ufw allow 5433/tcp
```

Answer (score -5):

The another solution is service volume, You can define a service volume and mount host's PostgreSQL Data directory in that volume. Check out the given compose file for details.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:   
    image: postgres:9.6.1
    volumes:
      - "/var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data" 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

By doing this, another PostgreSQL service will run under container but uses same data directory which host PostgreSQL service is using.

Comment: This will probably cause write conflicts with a running host PostgreSQL service

Comment: I think stopping host service will solve the problem in that case.