# Communicate to Docker host from Docker container

Tags: docker

I’m experimenting with docker networking, and I can’t seem to find a way to accomplish the following:

Start a simple netcat server in the host:

```
nc -l -p 5555
```

and then communicate to this server from *within* a docker container, e.g.

```
# grab the docker network interface ip
hostip=$(ip route | awk '/docker0/ { print $NF }')
# pass in the docker network interface as a host and try a curl command
docker run --add-host=docker:"${hostip}" --rm -it hiromasaono/curl curl docker:5555
```

The curl request just hangs and the host netcat server does not receive a request.

If I instead start docker with `--net=host` option, it works:

```
docker run --net=host --rm -it hiromasaono/curl curl 127.0.0.1:5555
```

and the netcat server receives

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:5555
Accept: */*
```

How can I communicate to the simple host netcat server from within the docker container without using `--net=host` (the default is `--net=bridge`)?

(fyi: I'm running docker server/client 1.11.2)

**Potentailly Relevant Resources I've Studied in search of an answer:**

- [Document how to connect to docker host from container (github issue)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143)
- [How to connect to Docker host from container (github issue)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8395)
- [Allow Docker Container to Connect to a Local Postgres DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database)
- [Docker Container Networking Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/#container-networking)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, based on two comments[[1]](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-39364200)[[2]](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143#issuecomment-46105218), the following unofficial hack seems to be working for me as of today (2016.10.27):

In the `Dockerfile` for the app which needs to connect to the Docker host, I added the following lines:

```
...
# netstat
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install net-tools -y
...
CMD (netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2" dockerhost"}' >> /etc/hosts) && \
        ...old CMD line...
...
```

This seems to make the Docker host available to me *from within the container* as `dockerhost`.

---

*Note to future readers: see also https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23177 — as of writing, this issue is still open, so there's a non-zero chance it may become official at some point in future and supersede any workarounds; though it may also become closed and dismissed as happened to its various predecessors.*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to look into, in order to solve this problem.

1. Netcat must listen on all interfaces (or at least on the interface Docker clients can connect to). Not on localhost.
   After you run `netcat -l -p 5555` if in another terminal you run `netstat -a -l -n | grep 5555` you should see `0.0.0.0:5555` or `*:5555`. If instead you see `127.0.0.1:5555` then it won't work and you need to fix this problem first before looking into Docker.
2. Docker must be able to ping the `docker` host and it must not resolve to `127.0.0.1` . Try `docker run --net=host --rm -it hiromasaono/curl ping docker`. If you see it's pinging `127.0.0.1` then your configuration is wrong and you need to fix this line: `hostip=$(ip route | awk '/docker0/ { print $NF }')` . If it's not 127.0.0.1 but the pings don't succeed then your network setup is wrong or the hostip is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

1.  Looks good to me:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

2. Ping is successful with and without `--net=host` assuming the docker hostname is setup as described in my question

Comment: Could there be a firewall blocking requests on port 5555? If the docker hostname is not pointing to 127.0.0.1 and you are able to ping the IP it points to from within the docker container then my guess is a firewall on the host.

Comment: Thanks again for responding: I don't have any firewalls active as far as I can tell. Are you able to successfully communicate to a host's "LISTEN" port from a docker container?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I am able to SSH into my dockerhost from within containers with no issues.

Comment: I'm able to do that as well, but I'm unable to connect to a simple netcat server as mentioned in my post: can you connect to a netcat server?