# How to connect a Docker container to PostgreSQL running on the localhost using a DATABASE_URL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, aptible

I'm following the [Aptible Django Quickstart Tutorial](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/tutorials/quickstart-guides/python/django.html) which described how to create and deploy an app Aptible's PaaS. I would also like to be able to run the Docker container with the Django app locally and connect to a local PostgreSQL database, however, and it is unclear to me how to do this.

The `Dockerfile` for the Django app is:

```
FROM python:3.6

# System prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get -y install build-essential libpq-dev \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If you require additional OS dependencies, install them here:
# RUN apt-get update \
#  && apt-get -y install imagemagick nodejs \
#  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Gunicorn. If Gunicorn is already present in your requirements.txt,
# you don't need that (but if won't hurt).
RUN pip install gunicorn

ADD requirements.txt /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--access-logfile=-", "--error-logfile=-", "--bind=0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers=3", "mysite.wsgi"]
```

where `mysite` is the name of the Django app. Its `settings.py` uses [dj-database-url](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) as follows:

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config()}
```

In order to connect to a local instance of PostgreSQL, it would seem I should follow the **Docker for Mac Solution** on [Allow docker container to connect to a local/host postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database):

```
docker run -e DB_PORT=5432 -e DB_HOST=docker.for.mac.host.internal
```

However, if I try this I still get an error ending with

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

It would seem to me that the app as currently configured is not 'doing anything' with the `DB_PORT` and `DB_HOST` environment variables, because it is reading these in one go from the `DATABASE_URL`. Is this the problem? If so, how could I fix this while still using `DATABASE_URL` as this appears to be the 'interface' to Aptible?

Comment: if you are using multiple containers it is better to use docker-compose.yml, docker has even docs for postgres and django https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/#create-a-django-project

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible to use Docker Compose on the Aptible platform; they have their own [Services](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/reference/apps/services.html#services) and [Databases](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/enclave/reference/databases.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by changing the `DATABASE_URL` in the `.env` file from

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://my_app:my_password@localhost/my_database
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://my_app:my_password@docker.for.mac.host.internal/my_database
```

and running the container, which I tagged `lucy_web`, like so:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 --env-file .env lucy_web
```

It was not necessary to change `listen_addresses` to `'*'` in my `postgresql.conf`; this was still at its default, `localhost`. (I believe this is because the `-p 8000:8000` argument maps port 8000 on `localhost` to the container).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, postgres is not running on a container but as a service on your host os, right?

Please theck below:

### 1. Check your postgres accepts connections on all ip addresses

Usually postgres listens to localhost only, that means, connections to other than `localhost` are refused. Each docker container is attached to a virtual network and communication from container to host happens through that virtual network.

Update your `postgresql.conf` file and add:

```
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                    # (change requires restart)
```

### 2. Use correct ip address/hostname

As stated before, container communicates to host through this virtual network. Make sure your are using the correct hostname or ip address.

- localhost

`localhost` is not going to work because from within the container context, localhost refers to the container

- docker.for.mac.host.internal

At least for me it doesn't work (docker-ce on a mac), see that host resolution is not working

```
docker run --rm -it postgres:10 ping docker.for.mac.host.internal
ping: unknown host
```

- use your ip address

I'm using my the ip address given by my dhcp server, ping works

```
docker run --rm -it postgres:10 ping 192.168.0.* -c 1
PING 192.168.0.* (192.168.0.*): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.*: icmp_seq=0 ttl=37 time=0.455 ms
```

So try using a valid ip address, either the ip of the docker device or the ip from your physical network interface.

### 3. Use a docker compose file

Use a docker compose file to run with either compose or swarm, see sample application here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#create-the-example-application

Answer (score 0):

Windows user configure their env to use:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://my_app:my_password@docker.host.internal/my_database
```