# Connect to Postgresql on Windows host machine with Docker

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, docker

I'm currently running a REST API on a docker container with the following **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install uwsgi
COPY awf/requirements.txt ./awf/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r awf/requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./
# Call collectstatic (customize the following line with the minimal environment variables needed for manage.py to run):
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "uwsgi" ]
CMD [ "--wsgi-file", "awf/wsgi.py", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini" ]
```

The Python REST API has the following DATABASE config in **settings.yaml**:

```
DATABASE: {
    engine: 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    name: 'name',  
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    host: '192.168.99.100',
    port: '5432',
}
```

I have set this `host:'192.168.99.100'` because this is the **docker-machine ip** output.

When I run the docker container without mapping port `5432`, I get the following error:

> OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>   Is the server running on host "192.168.99.100" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

But then I map ports while running the docker container:

```
docker run  -p 8000:8000 -p 5432:5432 img
```

And I get the following error:

> OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly This
>   probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while
>   processing the request.

I don't know if I missed some configuration. But I added the IP address range `172.17.0.0/16` to `pg_hba.conf` and also configured PostreSQL  to listen for connections on all IP, according to this solution: 
[Allow docker container to connect to a local/host postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database)

**EDIT**

**pg_hba.conf:**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             192.168.99.0/16         trust
host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16         trust
```

Comment: could you please add the `pg_hba.conf` to your question?

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl Yes, sure. I added it.

Comment: hmm, any information in your `postgresql.log` or, what do you see if you shell into docker and try to connect manually?

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl nothinh on `postgresql.log`. And how could I connect manually into docker?

Comment: `docker exec -it <your-image-name> sh` should do the trick

Comment: @ThomasSchwärzl I can ping my host machine ip (`192.168.99.100`) without problems.