# Unable to connect containerized app to containerized postgres, receiving dial tcp connection refused error

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

This community is my last resort for this problem, as I have been fighting with this for several hours now.

I have a go app running in one container, in the other container I am running a postgres db. I am able to connect to the postgres db from my go application as long as **only** my postgres is within a container, and my go app is running locally as usual. However, when my go app is trying to access the postgres from within a docker container i am getting the following **error**:

```
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Below I try to provide enough information, but will gladly add more if requested.

---

I have 2 docker containers running with the following **ports**:

- go application, port info: 8081/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8081
- postgres db, port info: 5432/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080

---

I am **running** the go app with:

```
docker run -it --rm --name gographqlserver --link postgresdb:postgres -d -p 8081:8081 gogogopher;
```

and the postgres db with:

```
docker run -it --rm --name postgresdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=hello123 -d -p 8080:5432 postgresimage;
```

both containers can be started without any problems.

---

I have also tried **connecting** both containers within a `docker network`, which did not help.

---

help would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow docker container to connect to a local/host postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using `localhost` address within the container which is not the same as your host's address. You should do one of the following instead:

- Use your **actual** host's IP from app's container
- Use `postgresdb` container's IP with **the native port (5432)**. You can discover this IP using `docker inspect postgresdb`.
- Use `postgresdb` as host name and the native port (5432) when connecting both containers to the same network

Comment: Your third solution worked like a charm. Thank you so much!