# Docker localhost connection blocked by UFW

Tags: docker, networking, ubuntu-18.04, ufw

**Situation**

I'm trying to learn how to use docker on my local machine. The local machine is set up to only route traffic through a VPN. The default UFW policy is to `DENY` all incoming and outgoing traffic (except through a VPN).

**Problem**

When I try to launch a Docker container `docker container run -p 80:80 nginx`, I cannot connect to the nginx container using localhost *in my browser*.

However, I can connect to the local nginx container through telnet

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

The reason I know that UFW may be causing this is because once I disable UFW, I'm able to connect to localhost in the browser with no problem.

**Question**

How do I connect to my local nginx container from my browser when UFW is set to deny all connections?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

**Solution**

```
ufw allow out on docker0 from 172.17.0.0/16
```

Since I know the specific port that nginx uses, I can also make this rule more strict by doing

```
ufw allow out on docker0 from 172.17.0.0/16 port 80 proto tcp
```

**Explanation**

Docker creates a new interface for containers and you can see it by running `ifconfig`:

```
docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a4:5e:e9:9c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 87  bytes 17172 (17.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 117  bytes 14956 (14.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

This interface routes traffic through 172.17.xxx.xxx. You can read more about how I found that netmask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249288/10873879).

This gives us all the information we need to write a rule. If you are publishing the container on a different port, you can check for the port number and protocol by doing the following:

1. Find the ID of you container `docker container ls`
2. Find the Port of your container `docker container port {id}`