# Connecting to postgresql from grafana

Tags: postgresql, grafana

Connecting to postgresql-11.5.1 from grafana is not working.
I installed postgres on my local and created a grafana and trying to connect, 
but i get the usual error: 
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
am NOT using postgresql on docker, its just on my local on windows 10.
because the answers that is available on stackoverflow is related to docker.
Please help..

Comment: I have a similar issue with grafana, both running in containers (postgre in microk8s). After running some queries it hangs and no response.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I deployed Grafana locally with Docker and was attempting to use the Postgres plugin to connect to my local installation of Postgres. I had to use `host.docker.internal` as the host instead of `localhost` which was causing the same error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### **Grafana normal installation**

Please do check these configuration files for Postgresql.

- /etc/postgresql//main/postgresql.conf
- /etc/postgresql//main/pb_hba.conf

Client authentication is maintained by making changes to `pb_hba.conf`. Make sure it has this line for local authentication.

```
 [TYPE]    [DATABASE]    [USER]    [ADDRESS]    [METHOD]

 host        all           all      127.0.0.1/32    md5
```

---

### **Grafana installed with docker**

The Grafana instance now lives in a different network and Postgres will have a remote connection with it. By default, the local connection is available only. To enable remote,

> sudo vim /etc/postgresql//main/postgresql.conf

Change `#listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `#listen_addresses = '*'`.

Obtain docker bridge network interface info in your terminal by typing.

```
 ip addr

........

docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group 
 default 
    link/ether 02:42:da:5e:5e:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:daff:fe5e:5e95/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Here **inet 172.17.0.1/16** refers to

- Network : 172.17.0.0/16
- IP : 172.17.0.1

Allow this network `172.17.0.0/16` from your machine in `pb_hba.conf`.

```
 host    all             all             172.17.0.0/16           md5
```

Now, use the ip address (172.17.0.1) obtained from `ip addr` from your machine in place of localhost as Grafana data source address.

**Reference**

> [Allow docker container to connect to a local/host postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database?noredirect=1&lq=1)
>
> https://blog.jsinh.in/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-postgresql-database-server/#.XXYs2HUvNuS

Answer (score 1):

On my setup, Grafana and postgreSQL run on the same machine.

Connection worked only if I used

`127.0.0.1:2345`

and it did not work with the local IP of the machine! (`192.168.x.x:2345`).

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker network ls`
and then inspect the network on which your container is running (for me it was bridge)

Then, run `docker network inspect postgres_container_network_name`

It will show the "IPv4Address": "172.xx.x.x/16" for that container, try using that in Grafana Datasource as `host:port`