# Spring Boot database connection does not work when in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a SpringBoot application, that runs perfectly on Tomcat and connects to a Postgres database.

e.g. **application.properties**

```
# approval datasource
spring.datasource2.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource2.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/approval
spring.datasource2.username=postgres
spring.datasource2.password=
```

Next I have Dockerised the application:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:14
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} nexct-approval-service.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/nexct-approval-service.jar"]
```

I can access a restful service in the application, however it is giving the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Everything is running on `localhost` and I plan to deploy this to a linux server where everying runs on the same host too.

**Question**

Why does docker seem to change the host access?  How do I configure this so that it can access the database using docker?

Comment: Are you using docker-compose?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, nope I am not. Should I be?  I don't have much docker experience

Comment: Ok adding docker-compose in answer, which works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will read up on how docker-compose works.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it looks like `docker-compose.yml` will create a new postrgres database.  I need to connect to an existing database that is used by multiple applications.

Comment: So you have problem in connecting app running in Docker container with Postgres installed in system and running?

Comment: Yes, but I have just seen your answer. I am giving it a try. I looks like it will work with an existing database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218210/discussion-between-muhammad-waqas-dilawar-and-richard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for Mac:** Inside your docker container simply have the db host set to `host.docker.internal`. This will be forwarded to the host the docker container is running on. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50394434/6332074)

**Solution for Linux:**
Actually what you really need to do is connect your container with Postgres running on host system, so for that we need to tell Docker to set network mode to host.

```
  docker run -it --network=host -p 8081:8081 --name containerName 'imageName'
```

Or using `docker-compose.yml`:

To start the containers just issue following command `docker-compose up`

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  configurator:
    container_name: 'nameOfContainer'
    image: 'imageName'
    network_mode: "host"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: on-failure
```

For further learning please follow the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).

Comment: What should the `nameOfContainer` and `imageName` be? Surly if I build the docker image on a new server, this will be different?

Comment: **nameOfContainer** can be anything and you can tag image while building for name consistency. **docker build -t imageName:tagName .**

Comment: If I change the entry in `application.properties` to `spring.datasource2.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://my-postgres:5432/approval`, I get the following error: `HikariPool-1 - jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.`

Comment: Kindly join me in chat.

Comment: I think we need more entries here to chat?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Check in question comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218211/discussion-between-richard-and-muhammad-waqas-dilawar).

Comment: @Richard updated the answer. This is how it works now. I've tested in Ubuntu.

Comment: I am inexperienced with docker-compose.  I tried your answer above, but on `docker-compose up`, I get:  `Pulling configurator (nexct-approval-service-image:)...
ERROR: The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed. If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your data before continuing.
Continue with the new image? [yN]y
Pulling configurator (nexct-approval-service-image:)...
ERROR: pull access denied for nexct-approval-service-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

Comment: DId you try command  `docker run -it --network=host -p 8081:8081 --name containerName 'imageName'`

Comment: No, I didn't, will try thanks.  I thought the yml file would build it. But I a was wrong.

Comment: Check the chat window, I've posted some comments there.

Comment: So is it better to use the `Dockerfile` only and not use `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Dockerfile is used to build image and docker-compose is used to build that image based on Dockerfile and then run it.

Comment: I'm confused. Do I need to do `docker run -it --network=host -p 8081:8081 --name containerName 'imageName'` AND or OR the `docker-compose.yml` file config above?

Comment: This is command `docker run -it --network=host -p 8081:8081 --name containerName 'imageName'`

Comment: So then do I need `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Do I run `docker build` before?

Comment: Extended discussion should be in chat.