# Connection between containerised springboot application and non-containerised postgres db; both running locally

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, containers

I have a springboot application (running locally) which connects to postgres db installed locally on my machine.

But when i containerise my springboot application **only** and run as docker container locally; it fails to connects to postgress db and gets error which says :

**"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections"**

**Docker command that i am running to build the image :**

docker build -t accounts:latest .

**Docker command that i am running to start the container :**

```
docker run --name accounts --network=host accounts:latest
```

Here are few main files of my application for reference :

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: Password@123

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk
COPY target/accounts.jar accounts.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "accounts.jar"]
```

When i replace "localhost" in "spring.datasource.url" property of application.yml with the actual IP of my machine then maven build fails due to test case failure and it says :

**"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "*My Machine IP Address*", user "postgres", database "postgres", no encryption"**

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

I don't want to go with postgres db running as docker container.

Comment: Probably valuable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249112/allow-docker-container-to-connect-to-a-local-host-postgres-database

Comment: If you running it in a container, you are not running it locally.  It runs inside a virtual machine which intentionally separated.

Comment: Add docker compose file, and let us test it